# How to stop current from passing through a transistor?

Tags: transistors, current

I have this circuit.  When sw1 is open the LED should be off. The thing is, some current passes through the transistor even though it's off making the LED light up dimly. Is there a way to fix this, or is the problem inherent with the transistors I'm using?

[image]

Comment: Hey bro, welcome to the site. Could you tell us what kind of transistor that is? Is it a bipolar transistor? Or is it a FET or MOSFET? Can you share the part number with us?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you have no current limiting resistors at all in the circuit.

You've probably damaged the transistor and the LED.

The base junction (base to emitter) is like a diode.  When the voltage difference between the base and emitter is more than 0.7V, it conducts current.  It will conduct as much current as your source can deliver.  The base-emitter junction can't handle a lot of current, though.  It will burn out rather quickly.  Your circuit has the power source connected straight to the base and the emitter.  As much current will flow through there as your battery can deliver.

Light emitting diodes (LEDs) are also diodes (it's right there in the name.)  Once the voltage difference across the diode is high enough, the LED will conduct as much current as the battery will deliver.  LEDs can't handle a lot of current, though, so it will be damaged and probably destroyed.

- You need a resistor in series between the switch and the base of the transistor.
- You need a resistor in series between the battery positive terminal and the LED.
- The values of the resistors depend on the type of transistor, the type of LED, the voltage of the battery, and how bright you want the LED to light up.

There are questions (and answers) on this site giving details for calculating resistor values.

Comment: You're right, it is broken. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

**your problem has to do with you using a floating input**

*I will explain why/how and what it is. I also added a edited drawing of your drawing below which fixes your problem and 2 other possible problems*

the switch connects the transistor to + or air, however this air connection will cause it to pick up static electricity and radio signals.
**to fix it:**
just simply add a resistor between the gate(gate is base) and the ground of the transistor *(where the switch is connected to turn it on and of)*, this can be a high value such as 100K or 10K. if you use a mosfet or a transistor with a high gate resistance it might never turn of if you don't add that resistor.

*Now your led should go off when the switch is of,
I will now talk about 2 different possible problems in the schematic not directly related to your problem, but possible useful to protect against.*

**however it might not go on if you use a normal transistor, it probably wouldn't really have went on to begin with if it was a normal transistor unless it is dead**,
*(you probably didn't use a normal one because for a normal transistor this circuit likely would have worked, I estimate you use something like a mosfet in a standard transistor casing.(please check the datasheet to make sure you have the right pins since mosfets sometimes use a different layout and can be damaged when connected incorrectly))*
this is because for a normal transistor the resistance between gate and source, or base and emitter(base and emiter is typically used for such transistors) is near 0.
so you would cause a short cirquit and the current will go directly to ground instead of the led. with a mosfet this will not happen because for a mosfet or a transistor with a gate instead of a base it typically acts more like a capacitor which is voltage based while a typical base based transistor is based on current.
**to fix this other problem** add a small resistor between the switch and the base(gate/switch) of the transistor.

**as a last thing your circuit's led might also easily fry itself** so add a resistor in front of your led to limit the current. for this use the following formula: minimum Resistor=(Voltage power supply-Voltage drop led(typically 1.8V to 4.2V, or for powerleds the rated voltage)-voltage drop transistor(typically 0.7V)/current the led can handle in Amps(20ma=0,02A for example). while this won't affect your current problem and might not be needed in your specific case, since I don't know the led type and voltage I still add this because otherwise once your circuit works properly it might directly burn the led, which typically isn't good.

**Visual.**
See the following edited image for the solution. R1 is the one needed to fix your circuit you can add something like 10K or 100K. R2 and R3 are optional and not directly related to your problem, adding them will make it more general and more secure, if you don't add them something else might break.[image]

Comment: The noise is in the order of mV which wouldnt be enough to drive enough current from the base to light up the LED.

Comment: I once might have thought that as well, but especially if it has a high internal resistance between the base and emiter, then a small amount will be a lot, often in high amplification transistors this can be a real problem, mosfets and logic level transistors also often have that problem.

you can try it yourself by not connecting the gate/base an then the led will often still go on slightly, if not touch the gate/base with a wire or your finger and typically it will light up. you can also see this in the Arduino analog inputs which have a +-2Mohm resistance.

Comment: Do the math for a frequency range of 100Hz and write it down to your answer.

Comment: it seems not relevant, but in reality it often is, especially since I don't know the type of transistor, something like a bc338 should likely work in the old circuit, however almost any logic level transistor, mosfet or high amplification transistor will not work in the old schematic because ti will likely trigger from the static and radio or it's own current charge.  the other option would be that the transistor is broken, but then it would be likely that the led was also broken, unless the transistor was connected wrong since the pinout sometimes differs, for example transistors and mosfets

Comment: Well I havent ever really tried it...You could be right.

Comment: this doesn't look like very sensitive equipement which needs acurate readings, it just needs to be on or off, adding complex calculations would make this answer unusable to the original question poster. above all such a calculation would rely on a lot of speciffics which you should know if that 100hz thing was serious. the thing important here is that there is a problem which can be solved by adding a pull down resistor. there is no need to make it more complicated, we are not looking at serious induction or such, mostly just statics/storage and discharging it.

Comment: I recommend the arduino method if you have a arduino uno, just connect a wire to the analog port and then constantly read it. or if you have a mosfet then you can try the led thing as well, many transistors will also do it, but some will work normally as you said. however know a led needs little current to work well, so even a BC338 might light up the led here. and we don't know the question askers setup, which makes a problem like this a lot more likely. especially when powered from something in a house this can be extreme.

Comment: Floating inputs are not a problem for BJT transistors, only for FET transistors. You don't need R1.

Comment: @user253751 Depends on the transistor and the temperature. There's a common spec for current through a BJT with an open base: Icbo. It's a strong function of temperature. I suspect that the original circuit was overheating the transistor, causing Icbo to be high enough to light the LED.

Comment: @JohnDoty Well, today I learned. I've never heard of it being a concern in an undamaged transistor.

Comment: @user253751 I guess you've never run your transistors hot, and are too young to have worked with germanium ツ